# Reschedule timer in android

Tags: android, timer, scheduling

How can I reschedule a timer. I have tried to cancel the timer/timertask and and schedule it again using a method. But its showing an exception error:

```
Exception errorjava.lang.IllegalStateException: TimerTask is scheduled already
```

Code I have used it :

```
private Timer timer = new Timer("alertTimer",true);
public void reScheduleTimer(int duration) {
    timer.cancel();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000L, duration * 1000L);
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you post the code where you cancel the timer.

Comment: could you please give us the code you've been using to do that ? It'll be much easier to help you this way

Comment: I have added my code. I m not sure whether its correct or not. I have also tried by cancelling the timeTask.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you see the documentation on Timer.cancel() you'll see this:

"Cancels the Timer and all scheduled tasks. If there is a currently running task it is not affected. No more tasks may be scheduled on this Timer. Subsequent calls do nothing."

You'll need to initialize a new Timer when you are rescheduling:

EDIT:

```
public void reScheduleTimer(int duration) {
  timer = new Timer("alertTimer",true);
  timerTask = new MyTimerTask();
  timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000L, duration * 1000L);
}

private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: It's your timerTask that is the problem. Try recreating the timerTask when you reschedule the timer.

Comment: Hi I have recreated the timerTask. There is no error but the sheduled task has been stopped. Can you please update the code in your answer so that I can refer it...

Comment: The timerTask MUST be a new TimerTask... otherwise it throws "TimerTask is scheduled already". Thanks for the example.

Comment: can it is takes more memory if it is running timer task in background after cancel() method and rechedule it

Answer (score 4):

In fact, if you look in the [cancel method javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel%28%29), you can see the following thing :

> Does not interfere with a currently executing task (if it exists).

That tells the timer "ok, no more tasks now, but you can finish the one you're doing". I think you'll also need to [cancel the TimerTask](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

@Eric Nordvik answer is running fine.

One thing we can do is to **cancel previous timer events execution**

```
public void reScheduleTimer(int duration) {

    // Cancel previous timer first
    timer.cancel();

    timer = new Timer("alertTimer",true);
    timerTask = new MyTimerTask();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000L, duration * 1000L);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can use `purge()` so you don't have to initialize a new `Timer`.

> `public int purge ()`
>
> Added in API level 1
> Removes all canceled tasks from the task queue. If there are no other references on the tasks, then after this call they are free to be garbage collected.
>
> Returns the number of canceled tasks that were removed from the task queue.

Comment: It did not work for me.... I tried it... Can you give sequence of API calls for this?